# Handle oauth token in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

While running my load simulation in JMeter as follow, the oauth that I am generating from the system at the step one is override by a new one while I am in step 16(please refer the image attached), how to handle this in JMeter that until my all the transaction controller finished execution don't generate a new token. (Please refer the image attached and the description)

[image]

Description:

- In step 1 I am generating the bearer token for my application and which is going to use for my entire iteration
- While the iteration is running and reached step 16(till this it is hardly take 30 sec and marked 2) a new token generated for the user which I used in step 1.
- Is there any condition I am missing because why it is creating a new token because it is not reached the entire journey or do I need to something else?

Here is how I am extracting my token
[image]

And here I am passing this in step 16,
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This screenshot doesn't provide the full information as it's unclear how do you "generate bearer token" so I can only make some assumptions:

1. You're using a JMeter Property (which are "global") instead of [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which are thread-local so when the other thread is generating a new token it overwrites the old value, make sure to use variables, not properties
2. Your "token generation" logic [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) is incorrect and the [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) which does the extraction is being applied to more than one request.
3. Due to a logic error or a copy paste issue you're overwriting the variable somewhere in step 15, use [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to print the token value after each step, this way you will be able to localize the problem and find the problematic block in your script which causes the problem

Comment: Sorry I missed the token generation logic, I have updated it. Thanks for replying Dmitri